# Como atualizar uma View?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela onde guarda entrada e saida de caminhões. Nessa tabela tem dois campos do tipo Date, quero atualizar os dados desses campos. Estou usando o select a seguir.

```
  UPDATE V_TPL_ACOMPANHAMENTO SET E_POR = TO_DATE('08/10/18 22:24','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'), 
  S_PORT = TO_DATE('09/10/18 01:55','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') WHERE COLETA='EDB-TP-32764C'
```

Porém quando tento atualizar, aparece a mensagem de erro: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Causa: foi feita uma tentativa de usar uma instrução UPDATE, INSERT ou DELETE em uma view que contenha expressões ou funções ou foi derivada de mais de uma tabela. Se uma operação de junção tiver sido usada para criar a exibição ou a exibição contiver colunas virtuais derivadas de funções ou expressões, a visualização só poderá ser consultada.
Fonte [documentação oracle.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01732_data_manipulation_operation.htm)

Comment: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2821/trigger-oracle-basico.aspx tente uma INSTEAD OF TRIGGER